# How to disable a future dates in datetimepicker in xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, datetimepicker

I want to be able to disable some days in a future. Also I want to be able to disable weekends. 
I searched for the solution, but I can't find it. All I can find is about max or min date. That's not what I need. 
If anyone can help, please. Thank you!

Comment: You would need to write a custom control as those features are not present in the underlaying native controls being used by Forms